# Django Admin, custom permission checkbox

Tags: python, django, permissions

Please help me. I'm stuck in one place in my django project to generate questionnaires by teachers. I've implemented my own UserAdmin model, and despite is_staff, is_superuser fields, I have my own boolean field "is_teacher". When creating new user, if "is_teacher" box is ticked, i want to give that user permissions to manage whole Questionnaire model, but remove permissions for managing `MyUser` model(creating, changing and deleting users)

This is all I've implemented:

in models.py

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
        email = MyUserManager.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, is_staff=True, is_active=True, is_superuser=False, is_teacher=True)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password):
        u = self.create_user(username, email, password)
        u.is_staff = True
        u.is_active = True
        u.is_superuser = True
        u.is_teacher = True
        u.save(using=self._db)
        return u


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.username

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, module):
        return True
```

in admin.py

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given username and
    password.
    """
    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': "The two password fields didn't match.",
    }
    password1 = forms.CharField(label="Password",
        widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label="Password confirmation",
        widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ("username",)

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='password_mismatch',
            )
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(label="Password")

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_teacher')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]


class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'is_teacher')
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active')
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('email',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_superuser', 'is_teacher',)}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )


    search_fields = ('username', 'email')
    ordering = ('username',)
    filter_horizontal = ()
```

Comment: suggest you create a 'teachers' group with the permissions you need and then add that group to any users whenever their `is_teacher` field gets set `True` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#groups

Comment: Thanks for advice, but i can't do this that way. It has to be done like this: superuser is creating new account, ticking "is_teacher" field and all right permissions have to be added. I just don't know where to place that permissions and how to code them.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization

Comment: Yes I was studying that site couple times, but I'm too newbie to find out actual place where to code it:/

Comment: @Skiben I don't understand why you think you can't use permission group for that? that is what they are for

Comment: Maybe I just can't imagine how to do that for now, but this is my thesis project, and my supervisor said to me that it must be as simple as i wrote it above. He won't create special group at first, and only after that create user. Unless it is a solution to create a group by itself during first run of the program?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this. One is manually adding the permissions. You should do this in the MyUserAdmin class, overriding the default save method. Something like this:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    # ADD THE PERMISSIONS HERE LIKE SO:

    obj.save()
    if obj.is_teacher:
        # This is just an example of a permission you can add
        obj.user_permissions.add('questionaires_questionire_change', '......')
    else:
        # Remove the permissions in case a user was demoted from teacher status
        obj.user_permissions.remove('questionaires_questionire_change', '......')
```

Now, the other way of doing this, which I think is better (because it doesn't depend on saving the user models, and you can change in the future without the need of doing a run through all your users updating permissions):

You can override the has_change_permission, has_add_permission and has_delete_permission for your Questionnaire and other models you need, in their ModelAdmins. This is an example for your Questionnaire model (only showing change permission here):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_change_permission

```
class QuestionnaireAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.is_teacher:
            return True
        # If a user is not a teacher, let Django evaluate their specific permissions (a superusuer will always have permission if you do it this way)
        return super(QuestionnaireAdmin, self).has_change_permission(request, obj=None)
```